# Error adding widgets to a cockpit in SpagoBI 5.1.0

Tags: java, tomcat, fiware, spagobi

We have deployed a SpagoBI 5.1.0 using an pre-made vm image from FIWARE Cloud.

We've added our PostgreSQL as a read-only data source. We've also added a few datasets and made some BIRT reports with Spago Studio. Those reports work fine, so I assume the datasets are properly defined.

Our problems start when adding a widget to a cockpit. We choose any dataset and configure the widget, and then when SpagoBI try to render it, we get an error.

> Impossible to load dataset [bookings] due to the following service
>   errors: SbiCacheItem is not mapped [from SbiCacheItem h where
>   h.signature = ?];

It happens with any dataset, not only *bookings*.

Being a cache problem we added another data source (a MySQL database) with write permissions and set it as *write default*, but that didn't help. We also tried several values in the *SPAGOBI.CACHE.DATABASE_SCHEMA* configuration variable, and again got the same result.

You can find the stack trace for the error in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/KhEL8tJD

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbzhs.png)

We don't know what else to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit this file

*/opt/spagobi/All-in-One-SpagoBI-...../webapps/SpagoBI/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml*

and add the following lines along with the others *mapping* tags

```
    <!-- CACHE -->
    <mapping resource="it/eng/spagobi/cache/metadata/mapping/SbiCacheItem.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="it/eng/spagobi/cache/metadata/mapping/SbiCacheJoinedItem.hbm.xml" />
```

then restart the server.

A *write default* datasource is mandatory for this kind of analysis.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks Davide!
That worked and now we can add widgets to the cockpit.

Table widgets are working fine, but whenever we try to add a chart visualization widget we get a new error. This error takes some time to raise, it seems like it's doing some processing, it's not like the previous error that was raised immediately.

It says "No value specified for parameter 3"
Sometimes it's a 3, sometimes it's a 2.

Full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/KaQtm2C0

Comment: I need more info. Could you please put log level to DEBUG for package it.eng.spagobi in SPAGOBI_SERVER_HOME/webapps/SpagoBI/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties and retry? you need to restart the server to apply modifications

Comment: here you can find the trace with DEBUG log level activated: http://pastebin.com/BmYRyS0t

Comment: we finally found out the problem, we have UUID fields in our PostgreSQL database which is the datasource. And when SpagoBI tries to cache these data in its MySQL database, then it cannot insert the UUID fields. We have remove those fields from our datasets and now it works fine. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: i do not see the directory it/eng/spagobi/cache .. i am using the same version but not premade by FIWARE . any idea ? thanks